# Angular watch on input of type number

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I've added a watch on my model.

When the model is bounded to an input of type 'text', everything works perfect, and every change in the input field calls the function of the watch.
But when the model is bounded to an input of type 'number', there are some issues. If I enter numbers, the function of the watch is called, but when I enter letters, the watch function is not called.

The purpose is to validate the numeric input (that it's a positive number), and to show an error icon if the validation fails, but not in the first time the form is opened.
I don't want the form to be opened with a warning before the user typed something.

```
<input type="number" class="textInput" ng-model="currentFilter.filter" autofocus" />
<img src="..." class="warningImg" title="Value must be a positive number" ng-show="(!filterFormWithoutChanges) && validateInput()" />

$scope.$watch('currentFilter.filter', function (newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!newVal || newVal == '')
        return;
    $scope.filterFormWithoutChanges = false;
});
```

Comment: $watch is not called because the given string is failing the validations of the input, therefore it is not updating your scope. Refer to: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController for your validations

Comment: Thanks. I'll read it.